# React Native Animations simply not running

Tags: react-native

My issue with React Native seems to be project wide. Anything using the Animated API simply does not run. I am running React Native 0.49.2,
Nothing seems to be working, I have tried out several peoples code, with nothing ever happening. The issue to me seems to be whenever I call "Animated.Timing().start();" it never actually starts. Heres some short example code:

```
class Splash extends React.Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props);

    this.state = {
      ShowSetup: true,
      fadeAnim: new Animated.Value(0),  // Initial value for opacity: 0
    };

  }

  componentDidMount(){
    this.Animator()
  }

  Animator(){
    console.log("ANIMATOR RUNNING!")
    Animated.timing(                  // Animate over time
     this.state.fadeAnim,            // The animated value to drive
     {
       toValue: 1,                   // Animate to opacity: 1 (opaque)
       duration: 10000,              // Make it take a while
     }
   ).start();                        // Starts the animation


  }


  render() {
    let { fadeAnim } = this.state;
    return (
      <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>

      <Animated.View                 // Special animatable View
       style={{
         opacity: fadeAnim,         // Bind opacity to animated value
       }}
     >
       <Text>Fade In</Text>
     </Animated.View>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

No matter how long you wait, the value will not show up. Has become a big head scratcher for me as I am not sure what else to do

Comment: Don't forget your semi-colons in the ComponentDidMount, very important!! Also, I think you need to bind Animator in your constructor or bind it in the function declaration, so you have options.

Comment: Dosen't seem to be the issue.. I can't seem to figure this out

Comment: I am wondering if it has something to do with react navigation

Comment: Did you ever figure this one out? I'm also not seeing any animations starting and wonder if it's because I'm also using react-navigation.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  <View style={{flex: 1, backgroundColor: 'blue'}}>

    <Animated.View                    // Special animatable View
     style={{
       opacity: this.state.fadeAnim,  // Bind opacity to animated value
     }}
    >
      <Text>Fade In</Text>
    </Animated.View>
  </View>
```

I think the `fadeAnim` variable you declare at the top of your render isn't being reassigned

-- EDIT --

Here is some animation code I've used, the render is implemented the same way you have it.

```
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      topBoxOpacity: new Animated.Value(0),
      leftBoxOpacity: new Animated.Value(0),
      mainImageOpacity: new Animated.Value(0),
    }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const timing = Animated.timing;
    Animated.parallel([
      timing(this.state.leftBoxOpacity, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 700,
        delay: 700,
      }),
      timing(this.state.topBoxOpacity, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 700,
        delay: 1400,
      }),
      timing(this.state.mainImageOpacity, {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 700,
        delay: 2100,
      }),
    ]).start();
  }
```

Comment: No luck, I am also using React Navigation.. so I am beginning to wonder if that is the cause

Comment: Weird, When I try to run this I get a "stop tracking of undefined" error...

Comment: make sure you adjust the code to your need. your code should look like this
    const timing = Animated.timing;
    Animated.parallel([
      timing(this.state.fadeAnim , {
        toValue: 1,
        duration: 700,
        delay: 700,
      })]).start();